# This error is preventing me from building my UWP app on a new Xamarin Form project

Tags: c#, uwp, nuget

I'm beginning my first Xamarin project. I started with setting up an android project and I have gotten it working with the emulator.

But after following the instructions of this video
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbIvG8ripcw&t=590s&ab_channel=GeraldVersluis)
I get the following error when I try to build:

**Expected "!$([System.String]::new('%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Identity)').EndsWith('System.Runtime.dll'))" to evaluate to a boolean instead of "!$([System.String]::new('E:\***(PATH TO APP FOLDER)***\Notes App\NotesApp\NotesApp\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\NotesApp.dll').EndsWith('System.Runtime.dll'))", in condition "'$(_CoreFrameworkPackageId)' != ''
AND !$([System.String]::new('%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Identity)').EndsWith('System.Runtime.dll'))
AND '%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.NuGetPackageId)' == '$(_CoreFrameworkPackageId)'".  NotesApp.UWP**

^^ The error code I get for this is MSB4100

I also keep having the Nuget packages **Xamarin.Forms** and the **Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform** go missing from the references of my project even though they are installed within it. After restarting VS multiple times and toggling on/off settings that alters the project/solution heavily they pop back into existance.

These packages when they go missing give me 10s and I even saw once, 200 errors and they all disappear after turning on and then off again, for example "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" in the build settings.
But the big error above still remains.

========================================

- All Nuget packages are up to date and VS is up to date (and I used the repair tool).
- I've removed the UWP project and created a new one, and I get the same result.

If anyone can help me solve this and let me know if I've made a silly mistake it would be appreciated. I would like to master this.

If you need any more info let me know, thanks.

## Update 1

I've reinstalled my nuget packages and restarted VS and [this is my screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCyLG.png) Note I have the package on screen installed but not showing up in my references. Plus some warnings that go away when they feel like it.

## Update 2

I created a brand new xamarin android and uwp project template, did not touch a thing, and I tried to build and deploy the uwp project and I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Y04.png)

Comment: More details are helpful here. What version of Visual Studio? Windows or Mac? What version of Xamarin.Forms? What version of .NET Standard?

Comment: Visual Studio 16.11.5. .NET Standard 2.03. Windows 10. Xamarin.Forms 5.0.02196.

Comment: For a while I was having issues like this with my Xamarin.Forms solution. Usually, cleaning and rebuilding the projects giving me trouble resolved the package reference issues.

Comment: I've tried that quite a few times and I've just done it again and no luck. It actually just made that error that I posted appear that wasn't on the image I sent.

Comment: I'm not sure it makes much of a difference, but I am using .NET Standard 2.1.

Comment: It looks you missing same extension sdk, please try to update the UWP app's target version to restore this library

Comment: Nico Zhu, the target version is 19041. I will try change this and back again and see if this fixes it. For now I will try remaking the solution/project.

Comment: Andrew, I changed the target framework to 2.1 and it said it was incompatible with Windows 10 19041 so I changed it back.

Comment: I have no code to share, this is new xamarin template project

Comment: Yep, I know that, I suppose your template has not contained  all the assemblies, So just want to a blank project for comparison.

Comment: https://github.com/Tazwinator/Notes-App --- here it is

Comment: The error code is MSB4100

Comment: I run it, it could work in my side, please build your project and set the  selection platforms as X86 or X64, please avoid use Any CPU.

Comment: Still does not work

Answer (score -2):

I created a project that was not buring by many layers of folders, in my C drive and not my external exFAT E drive and it now works.

Thanks for your help guys.